# Tools to evaluate TCP variants in Linux?

Tags: linux

There are lots of TCP variants available (bbr, cubic, Westwood, reno) in the Linux. But how to evaluate the performance of these variants? Which are the popular tools used to extract the congestion window and RTT information?

iperf and other similar traffic generator can be used to generate traffic but how to get congestion window and other TCP metric information?

Comment: What is your performance objective?

Comment: I want to see how congestion window varies for each variants, when I run iperf or something similar.

Comment: You can capture your TCP flow with `tcpdump` and then read and analyze the capture in Python.

Comment: Users at https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/ may have good answers for this.